# onActivityResult received before login form

Tags: android, facebook, authentication

In facebook tutorials I see this sample code:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    facebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Using this code I receive:
onAuthFail with error= "Action canceled".

Removing

```
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
```

It works fine.

So my question is: Where to put super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)?
Before facebook callback, after or delete it. At moment without calling super.onActivityResult - code works fine. Can missing cause problems?

### UPDATE:

I'm using this in manifest:

```
<activity android:launchMode="singleInstance" android:name=".profile.LoginForm"
```

android:screenOrientation="portrait" android:noHistory="true">

Can this produce problem?

### UPDATE2:

Reason to put 'singleInstance' in manifest is: to avoid relaunching of my login form. This problem forced to current problem.

Comment: Which class does your activity extend? If you extend it from the normal `Activity` class, this should not be an issue. The [default implementation](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.3_r1/android/app/Activity.java#Activity.onActivityResult%28int%2Cint%2Candroid.content.Intent%29) does nothing at all. Likely your superclass `onActivityResult()` messes things up a bit. If it is your own implementation: Can you post that source too?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regarding your update:

```
android:launchMode="singleInstance"
```

does indeed cause problems with `startActivityForResult()` and `onActivityResult()`. See the [launchMode documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode):

> A "singleInstance" activity, on the other hand, permits no other activities to be part of its task. It's the only activity in the task. If it starts another activity, that activity is assigned to a different task.

Which means that the started facebook auth activity is not part of your current task and therefore can't deliver any result(s). If you debug this, you should notice that `onActivityResult()` gets called immediately after the sub-activity has been started *(which is way too early to have a correct/useful result)*.

I'd say change your launchMode to something different *(also not to `singleTask`, it has the same issue)*.

I'm not sure how the superclass method affects this though, since you claim this fixed it. In theory this should never work with `singleInstance`.

Comment: Twitter4j need singleInstance to authenticate, how can I handle twitter and facebook authentication on the same activity?

Comment: WHy does this limitation show up nowhere in documentation of `onActiityReult`?  I'm not used to writing code where you have to guess what the design is supposed to be.

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at `Activity.onActivityResult()` [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.7_r1/android/app/Activity.java#Activity.onActivityResult%28int,int,android.content.Intent%29), you'll notice that it is  sort of empty. This means the following:

- Removing it is perfectly OK
- On the other hand, the mystery remains: there is no obvious way how an empty `super` call could affect Facebook method.

UPD: alextsc's comment provides a valid hypothesis.